# Set up enviroments in Anaconda without internet

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Hey unfortunately i dont have a direkt Internet-Connection in my Office. Since a few day i try to set up an enviroment for using Tensorflow and Cuda in Anaconda. On my Home-Computer everything works just fine but when i copy the enviroments to the Office Computer i cant open Spyder anymore. First i got the Error-Massage:

```
"This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt
platform plugin "windows in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."
```

After i set up the enviroment variable with the Title `"QT-PLUGIN-PATH"` and the path `D:\Anaconda\envs\Tensorflow_GPU\Library\plugins` I didnt reseve the Error-Massage anymore but Spyder just wont open. I also included the path `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN` with the path `D:\Anaconda\envs\Tensorflow_GPU\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5` but it didnt change anything. (I also activatet the enviroment with `conda activate Tensorflow_GPU`)

I have no idea what to do anymore. Did someone of you maybe had the same problem in the past or some idea what i could try to solve it?

Thanks a  lot ahead!!

Edit1:
I have installed the following packages in the enviroment:
-Python 3.7.9
-Tensorflow 2.1
-Cudatoolkit 10.1.243
-Pandas 1.1.3
-Matplotlib 3.3.2
-Spyder 4.1.5

with the conda version 4.9.1

Comment: How are you copying the environments? How similar are both computers in terms of OS, CPU, etc.?

Comment: Original One: Windows 10,
                      Intel Core i7 7th Generation,
                      Nvidia Gforce 940 MX.

Office PC:    Windows 10,
                     intel Core i7 9th Generation,
                     Nvidia Quadro T1000.

Comment: Did you try pack/unpack - https://www.anaconda.com/blog/moving-conda-environments